# Codeigniter set_select

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, validation

Apologies I can't post any code at this time cos I'm away from my desk, but I will try and explain my problem as clearly as possible in the hope someone can help!

I have a long form that submits to a method in a controller. To make things more user friendly I have split the form into sections. Each section has a hidden field that acts as a flag. The method that the form submits to is made up of conditionals that test for these flags. If a flag is found then the next part of the form can be displayed. I can also gather the data in sections rather than processing the whole lot in one go.

My problem arises when I try to use the set_select method to set a default value for select menus. The method is part of the CI system form_validation library. If an optional third parameter is passed to the method as true it should set that value as the default. However, this only works if the form_validation hasn't previously been run. This makes perfect sense because it is assumed that a default would only be needed the first time a form is seen ie. before any submission and therefore before any post data.

Ofcourse this isn't how it is in my situation. If i simply empty the post array then that defeats the point of the set_select function because any select menus higher up the form would no longer be able to be set to their last value.

Can anyone think of a good solution? I know this would be much easier with AJAX, but I want to make sure that everyone gets the best possible experience whether or not they decide to use JavaScript.

Comment: Posting some code when you get a chance might help make things clearer and elicit some responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that using set_select is probably not the best option for me, so I've added some code into my view files which will do this for each individual case rather than trying to use a generic function.
Not ideal, but is working!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use AJAX to break the form up into your 3 sections, submitting by AJAX each time.

THEN for non-javascript users (the few there are), I would just display the form in its entirety, and process normally.

breaking the form up sounds like a "feature" not a function.  Meaning that javascript users will be able to take advantage of the "feature" of breaking the form up, while non-javascript users will still be able to effortlessly accomplish the "function" of submitting the information.

Comment: Normally i would agree with you. But my form contains elements that determine what is displayed in the next part eg select how many people are in your party, then display the correct number of text boxes to enter their names. This is why i can't just display the whole form.

Comment: @musoNic80 I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.  It's actually 3 different forms if that is the case.  What is the DB situation? are these users(auth)? do they fill out the form completely only once? are the form contents stored in a the database? etc...

Answer (score 0):

what about doing it like this:

- split it into 3 different form in 3 different method
- on each method, set switch using session to check what form currently is
- add form validation on each of these form and check accordingly
- if those 3 form is `OK` then you can proceed to whatever process you want
- if some form is failed, you load back the previously failed form